# Atmega328 resets

Tags: microcontroller, low-power

I built a circuit using an Atmega328. I am currently powering this circuit using the mains (230V, 50Hz), which is connected to a 3 way splitter (See pic below). I then use a transformer and a 5V voltage regulator to power the Atmega328. I also have the driveway gate adapter plug plugged into this 3 way splitter.

N.B
The 5V is carried from the power supply by a 15 metres CAT5 cable to the Atmega328.

[image: 3 way splitter used]

Problem:
When I power on the Atmega328 it always resets itself. I think it might be because the driveway gate is pulling much current than my circuit, hence this drop in power causes my circuit to reset. Is this assumption correct? If not what might the problem be and whats the solution?

Schematic of power supply:
[image]

Transformer Specs:
Input Voltage:230V
Output Voltage:12V
Power:5.5VA
Output Current needed:400mA

Comment: More bulk capacitance, and make sure BOD is active.

Comment: Agreed with Ignacio. Do you have access to an oscilloscope?  You could measure VCC on the ATmega, one-shot, triggered on falling edge, when you activate your driveway gate.

Comment: I have enabled BOD on the Atmega328, what do you mean by more bulk capacitance, what are you referring to the micro or power supply, could you be more specific in your answer?

Comment: @bitsmack- Yes I unplugged the gate adapter and it worked fine.

Comment: "a transformer and a 5v regulator" sounds like a power supply solution which could well be quite suboptimal in design such that it barely works under good circumstances - such can be designed soundly, but there are a lot of non-obvious mistakes which are easy to make.  A modern switching supply will typically have a wide input range - if the mains voltage is dropping too much for even one of those, chances are you're wildly exceeding electrical codes, feeding a large load with long small gauge wires, etc.

Comment: Please provide a schematic to show how you are supplying the ATmega328.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Im using a CAT5 cable that carriers the 5V from the output of my power supply to the atmega328. The length of the CAT5 cable is about 15 meters long

Comment: @DanielGiesbrecht - I have attached a schematic of power supply the output of the transformer is 12V, and 5VA.

Comment: @Joey Is there any chance of running a mains extension lead so that you can have the power supply next to the circuit instead of 15 m away?

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Not an option.

Comment: @Joey OK, can you run the 12 V AC through what would otherwise be mains cable (i.e. thicker cable than Cat5 conductors and so less resistance) and have the rectifier etc. by the circuit?

Comment: @Andrew , what will happen if I still use the Cat5 cable? Is this dangerous?

Comment: @Joey You should calculate the voltage drop over the Cat5 cable for the current the circuit draws (remember it's 30 m distance as the current goes there and back). If the voltage drop is acceptable, then there's no problem.

Comment: The 15m cable carrying 5v is a critical fact which must be edited into the statement of your question itself - it's an obvious design mistake, and changes *everything* about the proper responses to your question.

Comment: @Andrew , I also had a bit extra cable so I wrapped it around a non-magnetic support, and then connected the wire to the chip, will this have a impact?

Comment: A 10uF output capacitance is MUCH too low! Should be closer to 100x that! The 10uF is probably there to offer stability for the regulator, but you still probably need a >1000uF capacitor in parallel with the 10uF/10nF cap

Comment: @DerStrom8 - but the datasheets says 10uF, can you give a bit more explanation on why it should be 1000uF, as this type of value is expected at the output of the transformer to.act as a smoothing capacitor

Comment: @DerStrom8 - Pointless giving advice to someone with out proper reasoning, the datasheet says 10uF but you saying it must be 100x bigger, without giving me any reasoning behind your proposal!!!. You can't ask someone to trust you when the datasheet contradicts your statement!!! This is absolutely pathetic and irresponsible of you to do such a thing especially since I'm working with main voltage, next time don't be such a vague person when offering help!!!

Comment: The 1000+uF capacitor is based on common sense assuming you have ANY experience with electronics. If you don't have ANY experience with electronics, you most certainly shouldn't be working on mains voltage. I *did* make a mistake when I said the 1000+uF capacitor should be in parallel with the *10uF* capacitor. The 1000+uF capacitor is required on the output of the *rectifier*. It is used for filtering and smoothing of the rectified sine wave. Otherwise the input voltage to your regulator will fall below the dropout voltage and your regulator will not regulate. Also, -1 for the bad attitude

Comment: @DerStrom8 - so you do admit it was irresponsible, as you said it was A mistake, any first year electronic engineer would have know that a 1000uF cap at the output of the regulator is weird, don't tell me I have an attitude when I was right, next time double check what you type before posting, before you give someone else advice, only to realise it was A mistake and the person who you helped, gets electrocuted, even though it's not your responsibility for what people do on this group, it doesn't mean you can offer bad advice and later come and say oh I'm sorry it's a mistake

Comment: @Joey No, the *placement* of the suggested capacitor was a mistake. You still need it in the circuit though, and the lack of it could very well be the cause of your problem. Your circuit is wrong, you still need the 1000+uF capacitor at the output of the *rectifier*, so don't claim you're right.

Comment: And "Any first year electronic engineer" would know that 47uF on the output of a rectifier is nowhere near enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your power supply sucks.  The driveway gate probably has nothing to do with it.

There are some obvious problems here:

The picture you show is clearly a 120 V 60 Hz North American style wall plug, yet your transformer is for 230 V 50 Hz.  The transformer will still work, but produce about half the expected voltage on its secondary.

The secondary voltage of the transformer isn't even labeled!  To design circuits, you have to do what we call "math".  That requires numbers to plug into the equations.

Even without doing the math, 47 µF is clearly grossly inadequate.

Do the math.  Since you didn't say what the transformer secondary voltage is, we'll work backwards to find what it would need to be.  Let's say the 7805 regulator needs 7.5 minimum to maintain the 5 V regulated output.  You haven't told us what the output current needs to be, so I'll arbitrarily pick 200 mA for sake of example.  C1 gets charged up at each peak of the power line cycle, so every 8.3 ms.

From the above, we can compute how much the voltage on C1 drops between getting recharged at each power line peak.

(200 mA)(8.3 ms)/(47 µF) = 35.3 V

Yikes!  That would mean, in theory, that the peaks on C1 would need to be 42.8 V.  That's beyond the maximum input voltage of the 7805, so this can't possibly work.

Just to complete the example, let's go all the way back to find the transformer secondary output voltage.  The full wave bridge has two diode drops in series, losing about 1.4 V.  That means the 42.8 V peaks on C1 need to be 44.2 coming out of the transformer.  For a sine, that means 31.3 V RMS.

Even if the 7805 could handle the required peak input voltage, the result would be horribly inefficient.

To fix this mess, use a proper bulk storage cap for C1.  1 mF would be a good start, although more wouldn't hurt.  With 200 mA output and 60 Hz line frequency, the ripple on C1 would be 1.7 V.  That's much more reasonable.  Starting with a nice round number like 1 mF is useful because the ripple scales inversely with the capacitance from there.  For example, 2 mF would yield half the ripple.

You also need to add a high frequency bypass cap across the input.  A 1 µF ceramic of suitable voltage right across the input and ground pins of the 7805 would be good.

Of course the obvious first thing to do would have been to look at the input voltage of the 7805.  You should see it clearly dipping below the minimum required voltage.

Comment: I live in SA, I couldn't find a 3 way splitter on the net that we use in South Africa, so I decided to put that pic. The 3 way splitter I used is rated for 230 V mains

Comment: And the transformer as an output of 12V ,5.5VA, and I have a 4700uF cap, will this be fine?

Comment: @Joey: Do the math.  I've shown you how to figure out everything for yourself.

Comment: I'm just confused on how you got the 83ms, everything else makes sense

Comment: 1 / 60 Hz / 2 = 8.3ms (the length of half a cycle of the AC supply)